# Spree Marketplace with dropship - "spree_suppliers" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

To the helper on this.

I am new to RoR and putting together the extensions of spree with the marketplace functionality.

Spree is up and running and installed these two gems;

```
gem 'spree_drop_ship', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_drop_ship'
gem 'spree_marketplace', github: 'dennisluan/spree_marketplace'  (this one is forked from the original)

The error is happening when I click in the admin / suppliers for Spree

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /admin/suppliers
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "spree_suppliers" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"spree_suppliers"'::regcl...
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"spree_suppliers"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Request info

Request parameters
{"controller"=>"spree/admin/suppliers", "action"=>"index"}

- Not sure where I have gone wrong
  I have done the correct install and migrates but this errors out at this stage.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try running `bundle exec rake railties:install:migrations`. This will add any missing migration to app.

Comment: @PriyankGupta - many thanks for the help and that solved the issue for me